# NHibernate hql tuple result

Tags: c#, nhibernate

```
hql = "select f, b from Foo f, Bar b"

var resultList = session.CreateQuery(hql).List<object[]>();
```

result list item is an array where [0] is of type Foo and [1] id of Type Bar

Is there a way to use Tuple<Foo,Bar> (or other generic class ) as generic parameter insted of object[] so one can skip casting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can, something like:

```
// The new Tuple<Foo, Bar>(foo, bar) constructor
Type constructor = typeof(Tuple<Foo, Bar>).GetConstructors()[0];
```

and then

```
.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBeanConstructor(constructor));
```

before the `.List()`

**addendum**

I've looked at *my* code (because I've already done this one or two years ago :) ), and I noticed that I preferred

```
Type constructor = typeof(Tuple<Foo, Bar>).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(Foo), typeof(Bar) });
```

There is a perfectly good reasoning for this: now (as of .NET 4.5.1) there is a single public constructor for `Tuple<T1, T2>`, that is `new Tuple(T1 t1, T2 t2)`. There is *no* implicit or explicit guarantee that in a future version of .NET there won't be a parameterless public constructor of `Tuple<T1, T2>` that will return an "empty" tuple. The longer `GetConstructor` form guarantees that the "right" constructor will always be taken.

Comment: This is really nice solution... can't believe NHibernate versatility