# How can I get NHibernate to map to a Tuple or Class?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have the following method to get a list of results from the database.

```
public static IList<T> Find<T>(DetachedCriteria crit) where T : class
{
    lock (_locker)
    {
        return crit.GetExecutableCriteria(InstanceSession)
            .List<T>();
    }
}
```

This generally works well. However, I've changed a method that calls the method above from.

```
public IList<FooBarResult> FindResults(FooBarTask st)
{
    return DataAccess.Find<FooBarResult>(DetachedCriteria.For<FooBarResult>()
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Task", st))).ToList();
}
```

Which works, to this (as I don't want to return the whole of `FooBarResult`, just certain columns on it).

```
public IList<Tuple<DateTime, Guid>> FindResults(FooBarTask st)
{
    return DataAccess.Find<Tuple<DateTime, Guid>>(DetachedCriteria.For<FooBarResult>()
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Task", st))
        .SetProjection(
            Projections.ProjectionList()
                .Add(
                    Projections.Property("FieldOne")
                )
                .Add(
                    Projections.Property("FieldTwo")
                )
        )
    )
    .ToList();
}
```

I was hoping that the `Find` method at the top would automatically cast the entries of the list to `Tuple`, but it just returns `System.Object[]`.

Is there any way I can make it return a list of tuples?

Comment: Isn't it that it's `Find` that returns an array of objects (it must return tuples as implied by its interface) - it's `ToList` that returns `System.Object[]`?

Comment: Without trying to cast using `T`, the type of return result from `crit.GetExecutableCriteria(DataSession.Instance.CurrentSession).List()` is `System.Collections.IList {System.Collections.ArrayList}` and the entries are `object {object[]}`. I think the list part works fine, it's just that I'd like to get the entries as tuples instead of object arrays.

Comment: OK, thanks, I get it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `SetResultTransformer` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29006605/2642204):

```
var tupleConstructor = typeof(Tuple<DateTime, Guid>).GetConstructors()[0];
```

and then:

```
 return DataAccess.Find<Tuple<DateTime, Guid>>(DetachedCriteria.For<FooBarResult>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Task", st))
    .SetProjection(
        Projections.ProjectionList()
            .Add(
                Projections.Property("FieldOne")
            )
            .Add(
                Projections.Property("FieldTwo")
            )
    ).SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBeanConstructor(tupleConstructor))
).ToList();
```